# The use of protected member variables from child class and abstract parent

Tags: java, polymorphism

According to our professor, the use of protected visibility should be avoided at all costs. However, I'm a little puzzled as to why. Say We have this for example:

```
public abstract class Animal {

    private int maxSpeed;

    public Animal() {} 

    public abstract void setMaxSpeed();

}
```

Where each `Animal` would have a max speed that would need to be defined later in the child class. However, throwing this in:

```
public class Tutrle extends Animal {

    public Tutrle() {

    }

    @Override
    public void setMaxSpeed() {


    }

}
```

There is no way to be able to access the `maxSpeed` variable from within the overridden `setMaxSpeed()` method. Although a solution would be to set `maxSpeed` via the constructor of the `Animal` class, wouldn't be better to set the `maxSpeed` variable to `protected` and have it accessible to all child sub-classes to be defined later?

Comment: In this particular case, I would just move the `maxSpeed` field to a concrete class.

Comment: I disagree, @ILoveCoding. `maxSpeed` should be part of every animals' definition and that's why it's good to be located in the `abstract` class. However, I would introduce a `protected` getter for it's value.

Comment: Claiming that 'the use of protected visibility should be avoided at all costs' is a bit too much. Your professor is being fundamentalist about this. It is true, however, that `protected` leads to some OO design errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `maxSpeed` member is defined in the `Animal` class, it makes more sense for that class to have a non-abstract method that would set it :

```
public void setMaxSpeed(int maxSpeed)
{
    this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
}
```

The sub-classes (such as `Turtle`) may override this method to add logic, but they should call the base class to set the value.

```
@Override
public void setMaxSpeed(int maxSpeed)
{
    if (maxSpeed > 5)
        throw new SomeException();

    super.setMaxSpeed(maxSpeed);
}
```

If `setMaxSpeed()` stays abstract, it would make more sense for each sub-class that implements this method to have its own `maxSpeed` member.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access `maxSpeed` attribute from subclasses, you could:

1. Declare it as `protected` (your professor doesn't seem to like this very much, but I think he's lacking a suitable explanation)
2. Declare a `getMaxSpeed()` method in the superclass: if knowing the max speed from outside the hierarchy is needed, declare it as `public`; otherwise, declare it as `protected`, so that subclasses (specific animals, such as your `Turtle`) can know what their max speed is.

I agree with @Eran in that the `setMaxSpeed()` method shouldn't be declared as `abstract` in the `Animal` superclass, and subclasses could call `super.setMaxSpeed()` from their own `setMaxSpeed` method if they need to do specific processing when their max speed is being set.

Regarding why using `protected` is claimed to be 'avoided at all costs', or dangerous, etc, please refer to this [amazing newsletter's article](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue210.html). My personal opinion is that it is wrong to make such claims, or at least, an overreaction. However, as explained in the article:

> We should try to only call either private or final methods from inside our constructors. The reason is that Java always calls the most derived method, which means we could call a method on a half-initialized object.

This means that if you call a `protected` method from within the constructor of your superclass, and that if the `protected` method is overriden in one of the subclasses, then the code within that method would run **before** the rest of the class was fully initialized, which might lead to nasty errors:

```
class Animal {

    protected int maxSpeed;

    protected SomeClass someClass;

    protected Animal(int maxSpeed, SomeClass someClass) {
        this.setMaxSpeed(maxSpeed); // call to subclass method
        this.someClass = someClass;
    }

    public abstract void setMaxSpeed(int maxSpeed); // could also be protected

}

class Turtle extends Animal {

    @Override
    public void setMaxSpeed(int maxSpeed) {
        if (this.someClass.checkIfMaxSpeedMustBeDoubled()) { // throws NPE
            this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed * 2;
        } else {
            this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
        }
    }

}
```

In this very simple example, `this.someClass.checkIfMaxSpeedMustBeDoubled()` throws a `NullPointerException` because `this.someClass` has not been yet initialized in the `Animal` superclass. This kind of error is very common when using `protected` members, but claiming that `protected` should be avoided is ridiculous. Just be careful and only call either `private` or `final` methods from within the superclass' constructor, and you'll be OK.

Answer (score 0):

It is depends on requirement, If you want `maxSpeed` variable should be present in your all subclasses then put that variable in super class and then reuse that variable in subclass. for that you have to initialize that variable through subclass constructor and change modifier to protected for that variable.

But its better to create variable in your subclass if those are related to your subclass only,